How can I declare type on mapped elements?
I'm getting an error on the className of mapped elements. I believe TS is throwing the error because the map's children (MenuItem) don't have the className type. See the error below.
The mapped elements are part of the headlessui package. I think this is part of the reason I'm having trouble. I'm following this introduction to headlessui: https://headlessui.com/react/menu. This example is the third code sample on that page.
I tried to make the MenuItemProps interface to use on the .map function like this:
links.map((link): MenuButtonInterface => ()

How can I include the className type to the children of the .map function?
ERROR:
Type '{ children: Element; key: string; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CleanProps<ExoticComponent<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "disabled" | ItemPropsWeControl> & OurProps<...> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.


Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CleanProps<ExoticComponent<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "disabled" | ItemPropsWeControl> & OurProps<...> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.ts(2322)



import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
import { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuItems } from '@headlessui/react'

const links = [
    {href: '/home', label: 'Home'},
    {href: '/Test', label: 'Test'},
    {href: '/settings', label: 'Settings'}
]

interface MenuItemProps{
    children: any
    className?: any
    key: any
}

export const MyComponent = () => {
    return(
        <Menu>
            <MenuButton className='data-[active]:bg-blue-500'></MenuButton>
            <MenuItems anchor='bottom'>
                {links.map((link) => (
                    <MenuItem key={link.href} className='block data-[focus]:bg-blue-500'>
                        <a href={link.href}>{link.label}</a>
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </MenuItems>
        </Menu>
    )
}




Use as Prop Directly on MenuItem
According to the docs you can use the as prop directly in MenuItem to render an a tag and it will allow you to pass the className
Code will look like this:
<MenuItem
  key={link.href}
  as="a"
  href={link.href}
  className="block data-[focus]:bg-blue-500"

{ link.label }
</MenuItem>

Hope this helps you.

I couldn't edit my original comment:
In other words, without as='a,' I'm trying to pass className props to , which doesn't exist in .
When you add as='a,', you render  as an a tag and can now add className and href like any other a tag?
This is different from the docs' example because  is rendered with as='fragment' by default, so they are styling the  fragment instead of the child a tag and are ignoring what TypeScript would have a problem with?
So your solution is really equivalent to moving the className to the a tag child?

When using a fragment, you cannot pass a className because it doesn’t create a node in the DOM.
Additionally, if the menuItem is rendered as an <a> element, the className prop will be the one you declared in <menuItem>. If you want to wrap your <a> tag, you can set menuItem as a <div> and add the a href attribute as in your original code.

the issue that I can see is that you are not using the interface "MenuItemProps" that you have created in your component.
Since you are using Headlessui which already has it's own types, you can either use

type assertion



<MenuItem as="div" className="block data-[focus]:bg-blue-500" {...({ key: link.href, children: <a href={link.href}>{link.label}</a>, } as MenuItemProps)} // Type assertion here />




Create a small component, use you interface there and use it in the code



// Custom component for handling props
const CustomMenuItem: React.FC < MenuItemProps > = ({
  children,
  className,
  key,
}) => {
  return ( <
    MenuItem as = "div"
    key = {
      key
    }
    className = {
      className
    } > {
      children
    } <
    /MenuItem>
  );
};

// Use it in the code
{
  links.map((link) => ( <
    CustomMenuItem key = {
      link.href
    }
    className = "block data-[focus]:bg-blue-500" >
    <
    a href = {
      link.href
    } > {
      link.label
    } < /a> <
    /CustomMenuItem>
  ))
}



**Note: Answer below using

as Prop

works fine as well.**

These work, too. Thank you for the response. This was helpful in understanding how types can be used here.
